# How to get downstream job's build status and trigger another job?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

My Jenkins pipeline is set up like this:

I have a job A which is the upstream job and on completion of it, Job B and C  which is the downstream job's gets triggered. I have done this using 'Trigger Parameterised build on other projects' in the post build action of job A

What i need is, once job B and C are completed, i need to trigger another job - job D. And i want job D to start only when both job B and C is completed.

How can i do this? Can you please help or suggest any other way in which i can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In job D you could use **Build after other projects are built** option in **Build Triggers** section. In the **Projects to watch** field enter job names you want to wait for (e.g. Job_B, Job_C).

Comment: Thank you for replying , if i do as you say, will job D gets triggered even if job B is triggered alone or job C is triggered alone ? i.e. even without the upstream job if i trigger job b/c separately , on completion of it will job D get triggered ?

Comment: Job D will be triggered when both or one of the jobs (B or C) is completed regardless of upstream job. So the answer to both questions is yes.

Comment: My Requirement is : Job D should get triggered only when Job B and Job C is triggered by Upstream job A...

Is this possible ?

Comment: Ok. Have a look at this plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/join/

Comment: Sure...Thank you so much